# Shift image content with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Starting from an image, I would like to shift its content upward of 10 pixels, without changing size and filling in black the sub image (`width x 10px`) on the bottom.

For instance, the original:

[image: Original]

And the shifted:

[image: Shifted]

Is there any function to perform this operation with **OpenCV**?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is there a function to perform directly this operation with OpenCV?

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4413 (previously
http://web.archive.org/web/20170615214220/http://code.opencv.org/issues/2299)

or you would do this

```
    cv::Mat out = cv::Mat::zeros(frame.size(), frame.type());
    frame(cv::Rect(0,10, frame.cols,frame.rows-10)).copyTo(out(cv::Rect(0,0,frame.cols,frame.rows-10)));
```

Comment: This is a little bit nasty trick. It works, but there is unnecessary creation of "zero image" and copying. I belive my solution using [affine transformation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26766505/2740907) is more clean and better performance.

Comment: @pajus_cz, "zero image" will be created in either case, even if you are not creating it yourself. Also, copyTo performs simple memcopy operation that is much much faster than all the complex operations that are performed by wrapAffine.

Comment: Thanks! Second one results faster than wrapAffine for me.

Comment: What if you want to shift the image down ;)

Answer (score 53):

You can simply use affine transformation translation matrix (which is for shifting points basically). `cv::warpAffine()` with proper transformation matrix will do the trick.

[image: TranslationMatrix [1,0,tx ; 0,1,ty]]

where:
*tx* is shift in the image x axis, 
*ty* is shift in the image y axis, 
Every single pixel in the image will be shifted like that.

You can use this function which returns the translation matrix. (That is probably unnecessary for you) But it will shift the image based on `offsetx` and `offsety` parameters.

```
Mat translateImg(Mat &img, int offsetx, int offsety){
    Mat trans_mat = (Mat_<double>(2,3) << 1, 0, offsetx, 0, 1, offsety);
    warpAffine(img,img,trans_mat,img.size());
    return img;
}
```

In your case - you want to shift image 10 pixels up, you call:

```
translateImg(image,0,-10);
```

And then your image will be shifted as you desire.

Comment: Could you explain what the statement `Mat_<double>(2,3) << 1` does ?

Comment: It is not just `Mat_<double>(2,3) << 1`. It is the whole expression:
`Mat_<double>(2,3) << 1, 0, offsetx, 0, 1, offsety` which insert values into the matrix. So the values in the `trans_mat` will be `1,0,offsetx` in the first row and `0, 1, offsety` in the second row. As is shown as matrix `M` in the original post.

Comment: Creative answer, but CPU intensive compared to the other solutions.

Answer (score 10):

[this link](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781785283932/1/ch01lvl1sec11/image-translation) maybe help this question, thanks

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('images/input.jpg')
num_rows, num_cols = img.shape[:2]   

translation_matrix = np.float32([ [1,0,70], [0,1,110] ])   
img_translation = cv2.warpAffine(img, translation_matrix, (num_cols, num_rows))   
cv2.imshow('Translation', img_translation)    
cv2.waitKey()
```

and *tx* and *ty* could control the shift pixels on x and y direction respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function I wrote, based on Zaw Lin's answer, to do frame/image shift in any direction by any amount of pixel rows or columns:

```
enum Direction{
    ShiftUp=1, ShiftRight, ShiftDown, ShiftLeft
   };

cv::Mat shiftFrame(cv::Mat frame, int pixels, Direction direction)
{
    //create a same sized temporary Mat with all the pixels flagged as invalid (-1)
    cv::Mat temp = cv::Mat::zeros(frame.size(), frame.type());

    switch (direction)
    {
    case(ShiftUp) :
        frame(cv::Rect(0, pixels, frame.cols, frame.rows - pixels)).copyTo(temp(cv::Rect(0, 0, temp.cols, temp.rows - pixels)));
        break;
    case(ShiftRight) :
        frame(cv::Rect(0, 0, frame.cols - pixels, frame.rows)).copyTo(temp(cv::Rect(pixels, 0, frame.cols - pixels, frame.rows)));
        break;
    case(ShiftDown) :
        frame(cv::Rect(0, 0, frame.cols, frame.rows - pixels)).copyTo(temp(cv::Rect(0, pixels, frame.cols, frame.rows - pixels)));
        break;
    case(ShiftLeft) :
        frame(cv::Rect(pixels, 0, frame.cols - pixels, frame.rows)).copyTo(temp(cv::Rect(0, 0, frame.cols - pixels, frame.rows)));
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Shift direction is not set properly" << std::endl;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since there's currently no Python solution and a Google search for shifting an image using Python brings you to this page, here's an Python solution using [`np.roll()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html)

---

**Shifting against x-axis**

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
shift = 40

for i in range(image.shape[1] -1, image.shape[1] - shift, -1):
    image = np.roll(image, -1, axis=1)
    image[:, -1] = 0

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Shifting against y-axis**

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
shift = 40

for i in range(image.shape[0] -1, image.shape[0] - shift, -1):
    image = np.roll(image, -1, axis=0)
    image[-1, :] = 0

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: np.roll is exactly what I was looking for, even though I'm not working with images. Thanks!

Comment: How to shift it diagonally to top-right . i.e. top shift and right shift ?

Comment: You can do `np.roll(image, (pixels_x, pixels_y), axis=(0,1))`  for diagonal movement

Answer (score 3):

> > Is there a function to perform directly this operation with OpenCV?
>
> http://code.opencv.org/issues/2299
>
> or you would do this
>
> ```
>   cv::Mat out = cv::Mat::zeros(frame.size(), frame.type());
>   frame(cv::Rect(0,10,
>   frame.cols,frame.rows-10)).copyTo(out(cv::Rect(0,0,frame.cols,frame.rows-10)));
> ```

The code above only can be used to shift to one side (to the left, and to the top). Below code is the extended version of above code which can be used to shift into every direction.

```
int shiftCol = 10;
int shiftRow = 10;

Rect source = cv::Rect(max(0,-shiftCol),max(0,-shiftRow), frame.cols-abs(shiftCol),frame.rows-abs(shiftRow));

Rect target = cv::Rect(max(0,shiftCol),max(0,shiftRow),frame.cols-abs(shiftCol),frame.rows-abs(shiftRow));

frame(source).copyTo(out(target));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
h, w = image.shape     # for gray image
shift = 100          # any legal number 0 < x < h

img[:h-shift, :] = img[shift:, :]
img[h-shift:, :] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

My implementation uses the same as the accepted answer however it can move in ***any*** direction...

```
using namespace cv;
//and whatever header 'abs' requires...

Mat offsetImageWithPadding(const Mat& originalImage, int offsetX, int offsetY, Scalar backgroundColour){
        cv::Mat padded = Mat(originalImage.rows + 2 * abs(offsetY), originalImage.cols + 2 * abs(offsetX), CV_8UC3, backgroundColour);
        originalImage.copyTo(padded(Rect(abs(offsetX), abs(offsetY), originalImage.cols, originalImage.rows)));
        return Mat(padded,Rect(abs(offsetX) + offsetX, abs(offsetY) + offsetY, originalImage.cols, originalImage.rows));
}

//example use with black borders along the right hand side and top:
Mat offsetImage = offsetImageWithPadding(originalImage, -10, 6, Scalar(0,0,0));
```

It's taken from my own working code but some variables changed, if it doesn't compile, very likely just a small thing needs changing - but you get the idea re. the **abs** function...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple 2d filter/convolution to achieve your goal:

Taken straight from [the OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html). You will need to filter with a kernel that has height (desired_displacement_y * 2 + 1) and width (desired_displacement_x * 2 + 1).

Then you will need to set the kernel to all zeros except for the relative pixel position from where you want to copy. So if your kernel center is (0,0) you would set (10,0) to 1 for a displacement of 10 pixels.

Take the sample code from the website, and replace the kernel code in the middle with the following:

```
  /// Update kernel size for a normalized box filter
  kernel_size = 1 + ind * 2; //Center pixel plus displacement diameter (=radius * 2)
  kernel = Mat::zeros( kernel_size, kernel_size, CV_32F );
  kernel.at<float>(ind * 2, ind) = 1.0f; // Indices are zero-based, not relative

  /// Apply filter
  filter2D(src, dst, ddepth , kernel, anchor, delta, BORDER_CONSTANT );
```

Notice BORDER_CONSTANT in filter2D! You should now run the example and have a the picture scroll up by one pixel every 0.5 seconds. You could also draw the black pixels using drawing methods.

On why this works, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

Comment: Creative answer, but CPU intensive. Use the shift method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I first tried with [pajus_cz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26766505/19254), but it was quite slow in practice. Also, I cannot afford to make a temporary copy, so I came up with this:

```
void translateY(cv::Mat& image, int yOffset)
{
    int validHeight = std::max(image.rows - abs(yOffset), 0);
    int firstSourceRow = std::max(-yOffset, 0);
    int firstDestinationRow = std::max(yOffset, 0);

    memmove(image.ptr(firstDestinationRow),
            image.ptr(firstSourceRow),
            validHeight * image.step);
}
```

It's orders of magnitude faster than the `warpAffine`-based solution. (But this of course may be completely irrelevant in your case.)

Answer (score 0):

Python code some might find useful.

```
h, w, c = image.shape 
shift = 4 #set shift magnitude
img_shift_right = np.zeros(image.shape)
img_shift_down = np.zeros(image.shape)
img_shift_left = np.zeros(image.shape)
img_shift_up = np.zeros(image.shape)



img_shift_right[:,shift:w, :] = image[:,:w-shift, :]
img_shift_down[shift:h, :, :] = image[:h-shift, :, :]
img_shift_left[:,:w-shift, :] = image[:,shift:, :]
img_shift_up[:h-shift, :, :] = image[shift:, :, :]
```