# Efficient C++ way to shift a cv::Mat with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, bit-shift

What is an efficient way to "shift" an OpenCV `cv::Mat`?

With shift I mean that if I have a row like this

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

and I shift it by 3 positions, I will get a row like this

```
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2
```

Now I am using this function:

```
void shift( const cv::Mat& in, cv::Mat& out, int shift )
{
   if ( shift < 0 || shift > in.cols ) return;

   if ( shift == 0 || shift==in.cols ) {
      out = in.clone();
   } else {
      cv::hconcat(in(cv::Rect(shift,0,in.cols-shift,in.rows)),in(cv::Rect(0,0,shift,in.rows)),out);
   }
}
```

but I am looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shift image content with OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068085/shift-image-content-with-opencv)

Comment: @Kiran http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068085/shift-image-content-with-opencv asks to fill the image with zeros, not to fill the image with something like `BORDER_WRAP` so in my opinion that question is slightly different from mine. Furthermore http://stackoverflow.com/q/19068085/15485 does not seem concerned with efficiency and performance.

Answer (score 0):

If size of your array is not so big and rows=1 then you can repeat your array like this
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
Then for shifting it shift array's datapointer